# execute Second function and then on basis of first function response In Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I execute first function and then on basis of first function response  I want to execute my second function in Angular.

```
this.auth.user.subscribe((user) => {
  this.uid = user.uid;
  this.service.getProfile(this.uid).subscribe((res) => {
    this.registerData = res.document;
    console.log(this.registerData);
  });
});

this.service.getLeaderboardData(this.registerData?.profile_id).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res.document.records);

})


registerData = {
    profile_fullname: "",
    profile_mobile: "",
    profile_email: "",
    profile_distId: "",
    profile_taluka: "",
    profile_password: "",
    profile_uid: "",
    profile_id: ""
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You needs to use swithcMap, for example

```
_httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/api/my')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(output => _httpClient.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/${output}`))
  )
  .subscribe(output2 => alert(output2));
```

`_httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/api/my')` - here yours functions

```
funnction1
  .pipe(
    switchMap(result=> function2(result))
  )
  .subscribe(result2 => alert(result2));
```

Comment: but I I want to call in my component.ts file not in service.ts

Comment: const switched = of(1, 2, 3).pipe(switchMap((x: number) => of(x, x ** 2, x ** 3)));
switched.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

Comment: it`s an example of two function